# Passing Values from 1 List to Sublists in a Matrix

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, range, nested-lists

I am currently creating a **matrix without using numpy**. There's one following case:
If the number of integer input is smaller than the defined dimension of the matrix, 0 is used to fill the empty spaces. For example:
Number inputs = 1,2,3,4 ; Rows = 3 ; Columns = 2
gives (in nested list format): [[1,2],[3,4],[0,0]]

I have the following code for this case:

```
def mat(*Num,row,col):
    Out=[]

    for i in range(row):
      In = []
      for j in range(col):
        In.append(0)            # Initialize the defined matrix with 0
      Out.append(In)

    k=0                         # Index for number input list
    for i in range(len(Out)):
      for j in range(i):
        Out[i][j]=Num[k]        # Update values from integer input list into the matrix
        k+=1
    return Out

mat(1,2,3,4, row=3, col=2)
```

However, I got this matrix: `[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 3]]` instead of `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 0]]`

How should I improve to pass all values into the list in the appropriate positions? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just generate and append new rows

```
def mat(*num, row, col):
    matrix = []

    k = 0
    n = len(num)
    for i in range(row):
        new_row = []
        for j in range(col):
            if k < n:
                new_row.append(num[k])
                k += 1
            else:
                new_row.append(0)
        matrix.append(new_row)

    return matrix

print(mat(1,2,3,4, row=3, col=2))
```